# How to create a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've installed the Mysql program and Phpmyadmin program and I tried to create a database with a table in it. This is what I wrote and what I got

```
mysql> create table aziende(
-> ragione varchar (32) not null
-> email varchar (32) not null
-> telefono int (10) unsigned nut null
-> ); 

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email varchar (32) not null
telefono int (10) unsigned nut null
)' at line 3
```

Comment: Mysql has nothing to do with Ubuntu so this is off topic. Besides that: the error notice is clear enough don't you think?

Comment: @Rinzwind why do you say it has nothing to do with Ubuntu? There are other topics where they ask about mysql and sorry if I bothered somehow with this question but I really don't know how to do it. Do you have anything else to say? Maybe something that would actually help, not something to try to make me feel stupid

Comment: No this is a database question, the OS has nothing to do here (you would get the same notice using mysql on windows for instance making it  offtopic). There is sister site for that: dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have a question for you. Have you written these comments on all the questions like mine?

Comment: No? This is the 1st one I saw. I can have a look at others if you want but I tend to use the frontpage only and not go directly to looking at users. If you want you can also have a chat with us in ubuntu chat when you are on 20+ rep). I do know what I am talking about when it comes to offtopic/ontopic related questions though  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect, plus you spelled `nut` at one point.

```
CREATE TABLE aziende(
   ragione VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   telefono INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);
```